# Lua classes: how do I access the object when running one of it's methods?

Tags: class, oop, lua, coronasdk

I am using this for classes:
http://pastebin.com/DHVXsH37

Here is my code:

```
require 'class'
-- General node class and functions
Node = class(function(node, ID, x, y)
   node.nodetype = 'neutral';
   node.id = ID;
   node.x = x;
   node.y = y;
   node.fname = 'exnode.png'
end)

function Node:display()
    print( self.fname )
    local img = display.newImage( self.fname, self.x, self.y );
    img:addEventListener( "tap", self.onTap )  
end
```

When running the display function of an initialized instance. I get an error saying that `self` is not defined. How do I get the properties of the object?

Comment: Are you using `obj.display()` or `obj:display()` when calling your function? The former will not pass `obj` to the function (as `self`) the latter will.

Comment: @EtanReisner ohhhh I didn't know that, but after I tried obj:display() I got the same error.

Comment: If you fixed it, please post an answer describing how and accept it, so that others can learn from your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Etan said in the comment, make sure you call your method as `object:method()` and not as `object.method()` as in the first case `self` value is set to `object` and in the second case it's not set to anything (so has `nil` value). `object:method(...)` notation is a syntax sugar for `object.method(object, ...)`.